Gitlab Changelog Trailer in Template
We are attempting to have a Changelog : entry added to every MR and in our MR template we've added the line Changelog: added.  But we also have JIRA integration which adds it's own MR comments and these are appearing after the changelog comment, which I believe needs to be the last comment (Trailer).  Is there a way to make sure the Changelog entry is always last?

You can probably do it as part of your CI job, but there's no guarantee that no none will comment on the MR between your pipeline passing and merging. If you use merge train pipelines, that might work since those typically have to run and pass right before merge.
